# Declare sepperate Getter for private and public usage

Tags: kotlin

I would like to have two getters. One for usage in the same Class and another for when the Attribute is used in other Classes. Is this possible?

Comment: You would need two different names. There is no official way to say that something can only be accessed from another class, but not the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a list in your class. Internally, you want to access it as mutable `MutableList<T>`, but externally, you want to present it as a read only view `List<T>`. You can simply make two properties and have one be private. Furthermore, the second property can be a getter so as not to waste additional memory.

```
class MyClass {
  private val _myList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
  val myList: List<String> get() = _myList
}
```

This is a pattern I use quite often